# Why this C code give me 'free(): double free detected in tcache 2' error?

Tags: image-processing, memory-leaks

```
typedef struct image 
{
  uint8_t *data;
} image;

void function(image *img)
{
  image grayImg;
  grayImg.data = malloc(1024);

  img->data = grayImg.data;

  free(grayImg.data);
}

int main()
{  
  image img;

  function(&img);
  
  // will do stuff later...
  
  free(img.data);
  return 0;
}
```

What is the problem with this code? I just cleaned up the memory for `grayImage.data`. And It gave me that error.

if I don't free the memory of `grayImage.data` then program runs fine. Does it count as a memory leak. If so, How do I fix it?

Comment: You have one call to `malloc` and two to `free`. You can only call `free` one time for each `malloc`. The assignment `img->data = grayImg.data` doesn’t allocate new memory, you only assign the pointer to the allocated memory. At this point you have two pointers to the same memory block. Only one of those pointers should be freed, they will then both point to freed memory, and will be invalid pointers.

Comment: You said 'Only one of those pointers should be freed'. Then there is the other pointer that has no use. What will happen to it?

Comment: You don't free "pointers". You free allocated memory blocks. Many pointers may point to the same allocated memory block, but you only need to free it once.

Comment: Suppose you have this code: `char *p1; char *p2; p1 = malloc(100); p2 = p1;`. Now you have two pointers, `p1` and `p2`, pointing to the same allocated block. When you need to free this memory you can do either `free(p1)` or `free(p2)`, but *not both*.

Comment: How do I qualify a solution though. Like there's a tick on the top right. By the way, I am new to stackoverflow